# Android Location Service not working in Android 13

Tags: android, kotlin, service, location

In **Android 13** i create one **foreground service** which get location on some specific time.
but it's auto kill notification while app was kill.
It's issue accrue in **android 13** but **android 12** it's working.
Any have idea regarding this?

**Step:1**
Create Foreground service with notification which can update location after every 10 second

**Step:2**
It's working 3 App Mode:

1. App was foreground
2. App was in background
3. App was Kill
   In Android 12 It's working. But Not more than 15 minutes running Foreground service.

Comment: Question is unclear as to how you are testing (device make & model / OS version), as well as testing steps. Unclear if you've seen/taken steps suggested in: https://dontkillmyapp.com/